# E-mail Validation Using Regex not working for jsf?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jsp, jsf

[image: that is my lib] 
I am using JSF 2.1 for my jsp page. I have included an **h:inputText** and a **h:commandButton** inside a DIV tag that appears on click of a forgot password DIV. I want to validate the input field for a valid email address at the client side itself so I used **f:validateRegex** and "validatorMessage" but still it doesn't seem to work when i give a wrong email address say "123gmail.com" or submit it without entering any text. All it does is it reloads the page. Can any one help me...

Here is my editted JSP page code for reference

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<%@page import="com.fla.mbeans.ForgotPass"%>
<html>
  <head>
</head>
<body>
       <div style="left: 44%;top: 6%;width: 250px; position: relative;padding:20px;cursor: pointer" onclick="copytext()">
                <span id="fstyle"><ul>Forgot Password?</ul></span>
       </div>
 <div  id="fgpass" >

                    <div id="newpass">
                        <div style="position: absolute;top: 10%;left: 10%;">
                            <center><h2>PASSWORD RECOVERY</h2></center>
                            <h4> Enter Your Registered</h4> 


                  <h4>E-Mail Address :</h4>

                    <f:view>
                        <h:form>
                         <center>
                             <h:inputText id="cmailid" required="true" value="#{forgotPass.mailid}" validatorMessage="Invalid email">
                                 <f:validateRegex pattern="[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]"/>
                             </h:inputText>
                             <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{forgotPass.fpass}">

                            </h:commandButton>



                         </center>

                   </div>
                    </div>

                            </h:form>
                </div>
 </body>
  </f:view>
</html>
```

My Css

```
#fgpass {
    position: absolute;
    left: 65%;
    top: 4%;

    border-color: #009900;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-radius: inherit;
   z-index: 800;

}
#newpass{
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1000;
   height:160px;
   width: 250px;
  color: midnightblue;

   visibility: hidden;
   background-color: lavender;
   -moz-border-radius: 8px;
   border-radius: 8px;
   border-width: 3px;
   border-color:#444;
}
```

My js

```
function copytext()
{
    var unhide=document.getElementById('newpass');
    src=document.getElementById('mailid');
    unhide.style.visibility='visible';
    dest=document.getElementById('cmailid');
    dest.value = src.value;
}
```

Can any one tell me why its not working or any other way where i can do the validation at client side ..... I am new to this, please help (thanks)

Comment: Which JSF JAR file(s) exactly do you have? It's namely surprising to see the deprecated JSP being used instead of its successor Facelets. This suggests that you're actually using JSF 1.x which would then explain the problem of `<f:validateRegex>` not doing its job at all.

Comment: @BalusC you are the best Mate ..... I have uploaded a pic of the lib i use Pls Do help me and kind of am new to all these and am doing what i have been told to do .... and i come to know that JSP is deprecated only after you mentioned ... i hope the PIC would help you find my problem Please do help or gimme an alternate solution .... I will be so greatful to you .... And a million thanks for your reply :))

Comment: Just a note.  `_@9.aB%` isn't a proper email, but would pass this regex.  Try: `[a-zA-Z0-9]([\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+@[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,9}` And maybe wrap it in `^$` or `\b` or something.

Comment: @Suamere thankyou i shall try it and get back to you ....

Comment: Using a regex to validate email is generally not a great idea. Here's a page which shows the regex to parse all valid RFC822 email addresses: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html - I wouldn't recommend copy&pasting that.

Answer (score 0):

Email validation using f validateRegex in jsf.

Use the pattern `^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$` for email validation.

**Example:**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>

<f:view>
    <style type="text/css">
        .error {
            color: red;
        }
        .info {
            color: green;
        }
    </style>
    <h:form id="regexForm">
        <div>
            <h:messages id="messagesId" errorClass="error" infoClass="info"></h:messages>
            <h:inputText id="primaryEmailId" validatorMessage="Invalid PrimaryEmail [ Ex: udaykiran.pulipati@gmail.com ]" required="true"
                requiredMessage="Please Enter PrimaryEmail">
                <f:validateRegex pattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$"></f:validateRegex>
            </h:inputText>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h:commandButton value="Submit"></h:commandButton>
        </div>
    </h:form>
</f:view>
```